# IOS disable notification when game in focus OneSignal - Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, push-notification, onesignal

I don't want to show notifications when game is in focus, i'm using NotificationWillShow event to handle this from this documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sdk-notification-event-handlers,
This is working for android but not ios, in ios device notifications always shown to users, how can i prevent this.

This my code:

```
 Notification OnNotificationReceived(Notification notification)
 {
     Debug.Log($"Notification Rececived additional data : {notification.additionalData}");
     CheckRedirection(notification.additionalData, false);
     return null;
 }
```